# Invisible period after posting to prevent "gimme" answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

I hate to see "gimme teh codez" questions get the code-only answers they're looking for, because it reinforces bad behavior on the part of both the asker and the answerer. The problem is that if the question is asked and answered within a few minutes, the questioner can simply copy the answer and move on. By the time the answer is deleted -- if it's deleted -- the damage is already done.

So here's a feature proposal for dealing with this: when a low-rep member asks a question, *all* posted answers are visible only to 10k+ members for some set time period: say five or ten minutes. That's enough time for egregious "gimme" answers to be deleted, and/or egregious "gimme" questions to be closed, without the questioner ever seeing an answer.

This feature would only be active when a question is asked by a low-rep member -- say, less than 100. Somebody whose been around the site for a little while is unlikely to ask that sort of bad question.

Comment: Comments, anyone?

Comment: `[...] the damage is already done.` What damage are you talking about? By your own account, the question is appropriately closed and even deleted.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi -- the asker got their answer, and so they didn't learn anything about how to ask questions on StackExchange. They'll ask another bad question in the same vein the next time they get stuck.

Comment: Okay, we agree the questioner indeed *can* work his way out of this a few times, but the [question ban filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/164403) will probably catch soon enough those who cannot learn from close votes.

Comment: Yep, this is pretty much what automatic question bans fix.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill What about obscure tags with no knowledgable 10k+s? What about 100+ rep users who still post gimme-teh-codez questions? Have you thought of the consequences of delaying the visibility of answers? I think that this "feature" would do more harm than good.

Comment: Suggestions to punish new users arise on regular basis here on Meta, they will all fail. New users should be encouraged, in general, not get weird and original punishments just for being... new. The community is doing excellent work in downvoting, closing and deleting questions considered bad. That's more than enough, in my opinion.

Comment: Oh well, just an idea. Nothing ventured, nothing gained. Thanks for the comments all.

Comment: Just tossing this in here for future reference: SO has around 4K 10K users, of whom maybe half are active in a given week. SO gets around 5K questions from users with < 100 reputation every day. Oh, and: http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with this suggestion is it focuses on solving a problem in a way that disregards the potential effects on good users who actually do take the time to write good questions and answers.

While it's good to think of ways to keep Stack Overflow clean and on-topic, those processes -- or barriers to entry -- shouldn't discourage or limit good users from getting instant answers to questions they have. This proposed solution would effectively eliminate one of the big draws to Stack Overflow, which is that one may quickly obtain answers to problems and interact with the community to receive the best possible answers.

This also doesn't teach these users anything. In many cases, I've seen a "giv me teh codez" user change their ways with constructive guidance from the community. These downvoted and closed posts give them an opportunity to change their ways on *their* terms, using Theory Y management instead of Theory X.... but if they don't come around, then we shut them out.

As others mention, the question ban is effective, and users who don't learn will eventually be unable to post questions. This of course means they'll be some clean-up tasks in the interim, but that's just the cost we must pay for having such a great resource.